# How to install app as system app

Tags: android, root

I want to implement some root functions (like restarting phone) in my app and therefore my app must install as system app.

Is there a programmatically way to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: u can fire an intent to install, but your app needs to be signed from vendor, otherwise the user will be prompt to install

Comment: You may want to ask over at http://android.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Yes there is a way I'm posting late sorrt

Answer (score 0):

**How??**

In this method we will use a script that tour program will execute as root

**Why Script??**

Because we need to kill the whole app to transfer it to system

**Why I can't do it on installation??**

We can't because a as system app should be signed by Google (*like talkback*)

**So begin**

**Preparing Script**

The script is like copying the whole folder to `/system/app` partition 
(Just download `system/app mover` from play store and watch it scripts)

**Executing**

You need to start the script as root by calling

```
su -c " "
```

**Congrats**

You got as you system

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question. Also, the term is `voila`, this one means a very different thing.

Comment: This answer tells how the process of system conversion should take place